# Move edit notifications to the top of the page on mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, edits

I recently submitted a suggested edit from the mobile site. I forgot to keep an edit summary.

When I tried to submit it, I was redirected to the edit page with a yellow banner on top like the previous one. The banner had the usual "you do not have edit privileges, the edit will be placed in peer review" and "please keep edits substantial" messages. No indication  of my lack of edit summary. This confused me for a bit and I thought the edit was insubstantial or something. Then it hit me that I had forgotten to write a summary. I looked for the notification about the missing summary and found it at the bottom, in a normal font, and a bit camouflaged by the other stuff around it.

IMO error messages on mobile should be near the top of the page, since the entire page is not visible on some screens. If I was a newer user (who did not know about edit summaries) I might not have found it for a while, since the suggested edit banner outshone it and was on top. If there are notifications on top, one does not look for notifications down below.

So, could edit notifications/error messages be moved up top on mobile, preferably with some emphasis? (The old one on main used to be in a red font till it was replaced with the neat popups)

Comment: +1, totally valid request. I'd like the same.